# Is there a Pytorch equivalent of Tensorflow class "tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell"?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

guys.
Is there pytorch equivalent of “[tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/MultiRNNCell)” that stacks multiple cells?
Could it be torch.nn.LSTM()?
Then how to use it to create same network as MultiRNNCell?

Answer (score 0):

See the `num_layers` argument for [`torch.nn.RNN`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#rnn). Also works for LSTM and GRU.

Comment: Yes, what if i want different number of cells in each layers?